# Computing the eta invariant of a rather contrived operator on the circle

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, differential-operators, zeta-functions, index-theory

For physical reasons, I am interested in computing the eta invariant of the following Hermitian operator acting on complex valued functions on the circle with circumference 1. I define the operator via its real eigenvalues

$$\lambda_n = 2\pi \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) - u + \Sigma(n)\,,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}\,,\quad u\in\mathbb{R}\,,\quad \Sigma(n)\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$

$u$ is a constant and $\Sigma(n)$ is a set of values which I can compute numerically up to very large $n$, and I also know the asymptotics of $\Sigma(n)$ for large $n$ and small $n$. Alternatively, I can define the operator $\mathcal{O}$ as

$$ \mathcal{O} f(\tau) = (-i\partial_\tau - u) f(\tau) + \int_0^1 d\tau' \Sigma(\tau-\tau')f(\tau')\,, $$

where $f$ is an anti-periodic function on the circle. $\Sigma(n)$ are the Fourier coefficients of $\Sigma(\tau)$.

Without the last term $\Sigma(n)$, this is just the usual one-dimensional Dirac operator, which is a standard example in introductions to the eta invariant.

I want to ask if the eta invariant of this generalized operator can be computed, either analytically or with the numerical data for $\Sigma(n)$. Might it be possible that the $\Sigma(n)$ term can be treated as a deformation homotopically?

Many thanks.

Comment: @ChristianRemling  I've added a more explicit definition. Hopefully it makes sense.